# Whether proteus is simulator or emulator

Tags: emulation, simulator, qemu

By searching about simulator and emulator while looking on qemu I found

> A simulator is an environment which models but an emulator is one that
>   replicates the usage as on the original device or system

So my doubt is proteus is a simulator or emulator ? why ?